# Jquery datepicker not popping up on first click ,but pops up on second click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am facing an issue with jquery datepicker.

I am attaching the jquery datepicker to dynamically generated text boxes in  a javascript function.

The issue is that the datepicker doesn't popup at first click, 
if i place a break point or alert inside the javascript function, then the datepicker pops up on first click itself.

This is the JavaScript function i am using:

```
function CalendarPopUpOnClick(TextBoxId, HiddenFieldId) {
    if (TextBoxId != undefined) {
        $('#' + serverIdPrefix + TextBoxId).keypress(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        var dateTimeDueDate = $('#' + serverIdPrefix + HiddenFieldId).val();
        var dateTimeArrDueDate = dateTimeDueDate.split(" ");
        var dateOnlyDueDate = dateTimeArrDueDate[0];
        $('#' + serverIdPrefix + TextBoxId).val(dateOnlyDueDate);

        setTimeSpanBeginInput = function () {
            var dateTime = $('#' + serverIdPrefix + HiddenFieldId).val();
            var dateTimeArr = dateTime.split(" ");
            var dateOnly = dateTimeArr[0];
            $('#' + serverIdPrefix + TextBoxId).val(dateOnly);
        }
        $('#' + serverIdPrefix + TextBoxId).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                $('#' + serverIdPrefix + HiddenFieldId).val(dateText + ' 12:00:00 PM');
            },
            onClose: setTimeSpanBeginInput
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Are you sure you're not complicating things a little bit there ?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error

Comment: Instead of this : `if (TextBoxId != undefined)` you can use : `if(TextBoxId)` just a little short. Isn't it ?

Comment: @adeneo: is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: You're using a lot of long variables, selecting the same elements over and over with the same  complicated code. You could probably shorten this to half, in fact, I already did -> [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JmWST/2/) ??

Comment: @adeneo nice shortening, but the textbox datepicker is totally non functional. Not your fault, @Prashith needs to show how/when he's calling the `CalendarPopupOnClick` function. Also, I take it c# & asp.net are your server environment, but I can't see anywhere that matters in your code: it's straight javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All,

Sorry for the late update.

I have got this working with the following code.

I am using C# and Asp.Net as @adeneo pointed out.

I am creating two dynamic textboxes from C# code behind and adding the javascript function to onclik event of the textbox as given below:

```
 DeliveryDateTextBox.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:CalendarPopUpOnClick('" + DeliveryDateTextBox.ClientID + "','" + Hiddenfield_DeliveryDateTextBox.ClientID + "');");


DueDateTextBox.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:CalendarPopUpOnClick('" + DueDateTextBox.ClientID + "','" + Hiddenfield_DueDateTextBox.ClientID + "');");
```

and in the Javascript file i am adding the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
/* Get id prefixes for checkboxes, checkbox control elements */
var exampleId = $("input[use='proprietary']").attr("id");
var serverIdPrefixEndPos = exampleId.indexOf("exampleID");
serverIdPrefix = exampleId.substring(0,serverIdPrefixEndPos);

/* Datepicker BEGIN */
setTimeSpanBeginInput = function(){
                                var dateTime = $('#'+ serverIdPrefix +'timeSpanFromDeliveryDateHiddenField').val();
                                var dateTimeArr = dateTime.split(" ");
                                var dateOnly = dateTimeArr[0];
                                $('#'+ serverIdPrefix +'timeSpanFromDeliveryDate').val(dateOnly);
                            } //when calendar closed, copy hidden field value to main date field
$('#'+ serverIdPrefix +'timeSpanFromDeliveryDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function(dateText){ $('#'+ serverIdPrefix +'timeSpanFromDeliveryDateHiddenField').val(dateText + ' 12:00:00 PM'); }, onClose: setTimeSpanBeginInput});

setTimeSpanEndInput = function(){
                                var dateTime = $('#'+ serverIdPrefix +'timeSpanToDateHiddenField').val();
                                var dateTimeArr = dateTime.split(" ");
                                var dateOnly = dateTimeArr[0];
                                $('#'+ serverIdPrefix +'timeSpanToDeliveryDate').val(dateOnly);
                            } //when calendar closed, copy hidden field value to main date field
$('#'+ serverIdPrefix +'timeSpanToDeliveryDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function(dateText){ $('#'+ serverIdPrefix +'timeSpanToDateHiddenField').val(dateText + ' 12:00:00 PM'); }, onClose: setTimeSpanEndInput});

/* Datepicker END */



});//end document ready 
function CalendarPopUpOnClick(TextBoxId, HiddenFieldId) 
{

    if (TextBoxId) {
        var textBox     = $('#' + serverIdPrefix + TextBoxId),
            hiddenField = $('#' + serverIdPrefix + HiddenFieldId);

        textBox.focus();

         $(":input").bind('paste', function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
         var dateval =hiddenField.val();
              if(dateval.indexOf('0001-01-01')==-1)
                textBox.val(  hiddenField.val().split(" ")[0]  );
              else
                textBox.val('');  
        }, 100);
        });            

        textBox.keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
        hiddenField.keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
        var dateTime = hiddenField.val();
        var dateTimeArr = dateTime.split(" ");
        var dateOnly = dateTimeArr[0];
        textBox.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function (dateOnly) {
                hiddenField.val(dateOnly + ' 12:00:00 PM');
            },
            onClose: function() {
              var dateval =hiddenField.val();
              if(dateval.indexOf('0001-01-01')==-1)
                textBox.val(  hiddenField.val().split(" ")[0]  );
            }
        });
       textBox.datepicker().datepicker('show');
    }
}
```